# Android how to add a Listview to a Fragment instead of ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I know how to add a `ListView` to `ListActivity`, but how to add the `ListView` to a `Fragment`?

Comment: you can use ListFragment for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your class extend `ListFragment` instead of `Fragment`, like this:

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
    "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
    "Linux", "OS/2" };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```